# Which of these two java versions is the application actually using?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I'd like to know which java version my application is using.

But there are two different being displayed depending where to look.

1. Running the command: java -version

java version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode)

2. Package Explorer folder displays:

\JRE System Library [JavaSE-11]

3. Project > Properties > Java Buidl Path > Libraries > Modulepath

Displays JRE System Library [JavaSE-11]

4. Project > Properties > Java Compiler

Displays version 11.

5. Spring Tool Suite > Window > Preferences > Installed JREs displays the following:

C:\spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0\contents\sts-4.8.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre

(version 14.0.2)

6. Spring Tool Suite > Help > About Spring Tool Suite 4 > Installation details > Configuration:

java.runtime.version=14.0.2+12-46

7. In Package Explorer under "JRE System Library [JavaSE-11]" the following is displayed:

C:\spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0\contents\sts-4.8.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar

C:\spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0\contents\sts-4.8.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar

C:\spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.0\contents\sts-4.8.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\lib\jrt-fs.jar
....

all 14.0.2

8. Running the code below it returns 14.0.2+12-46.

   public class JavaVersion {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
   }
   }
9. Window > Preferences > Java Compiler

Displays version 14.

So, from the first four it seems it's using 11.0.8.
But the last five places seems it's 14.02.

Which is the actual version being used by the application?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your spring tools (which uses eclipse) has an embedded version of java.

Comment: If you are running within Eclipse you can easily override the version of Java you want to run.  There have been many posts on StackOverflow for "eclipse jvm configuration".  I believe it is under eclipse.ini with a -vm setting for the VM to use

Comment: Which one do you mean, when it's compiled or when it's run? When it's compiled, it's quite clear that's intended to be 11--expand the JRE System Library node and look at the paths to be 100% sure. As for when it's run, what does your Launch Configuration indicate?

Comment: @nitind Didn't know there could be a version to compile and another to run. Would like to use the same one for everything (11.0.8). When expanding JRE System Library it shows 14.0.2 (item 7 above). Where to check launch configuration?

Comment: @jkfe You can even e.g. generate Java 11 bytecode with a Java 14 JDK and then run that with a Java 12 VM in Eclipse that runs with Java 15. If you want to have for your project and application only Java 11, make sure in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ only a Java 11 JDK is configured and in your project Java 11 is configured as an execution environment, not as a specific JRE (should be shown in the _Project/Package Explorer_ as `JRE System Library [JavaSE-11]`).

Comment: @howlger I did that change. Now everything seems to correctly be on 11.0.8. The only thing that remains on 14 is item 6 above (Spring Tool Suite > Help > About Spring Tool Suite 4 > Installation details > Configuration > java.runtime.version). But guess that has no impact on the application.

Comment: @jkfe Yes, that's correct.